# Android: Should I use local Storage or SQLite (or similar)?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, storage

I am just starting to learn Android Development. I have to develop something similar to a Log APP where the user can save information.This is student project, so I don't have to use Users/Passwords, instead I am allowed to save the info using the Local Storage of the device.

The problem is that I will need to extract that info into a CSV file, and I am not sure if using Local Storage is the best option.

Which option do you think is more efficient?

Which one do you think is less complicated to use in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should directly make a csv file. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) for it is the official Android Database framework and the learning curve is quite easy. It even supports other Jetpack libraries such [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData) to make your Android development far more easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite. You can query the data from the database and write it to a cvs file upon need.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use Sqlite, and not raw sqlite but use instead Room. Room is architecture component by android and is actually just one layer above sqlite so it is easier to use and removes a lot of boilerplate code. For storing really little things like login information you can use SharedPrefrences. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/) is documentation about Room I suggest reading it.